# How to sum field in lightswitch app

Tags: vb.net-2010, visual-studio-lightswitch

Hi I am trying to create a small app for recording lieu time.

The code below does not return a total value for the users lieu time.

2 tables
lieu
Lieudate      date.
lieuAdd       boolean choice list True, False.
LieuHours     decimal.
lieuTotal     decimal computed field.

Users
UserName      string.
LastName      string.
Firstname     String.
Phone         Phone.
Email         emailaddress.

one(users) to many(lieu)

I want to show the total amount of lieu time a person has in the lieutotal field
a running total so when a user looks at their last record it shows the last transaction and how much lieu time they have.

code for computed field

Namespace LightSwitchApplication

```
Public Class Lieu

    Private Sub LieuTotal_Compute(ByRef result As Decimal)
        ' Set result to the desired field value
        Dim Total As Decimal

        If LieuAdd = True Then
            If LieuTotal = 0 Then
                Total = LieuHours
            Else
                Total = LieuTotal + LieuHours
                result = total
            End If
        Else


            Total = LieuTotal - LieuHours

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

End Namespace

Answer (score 0):

Since you are computing a total, you need to use a For Each loop. Assuming the name of the table is Lieus, your code should be something like:

```
    Private Sub LieuTotal_Compute(ByRef result As Decimal) 
    ' Set result to the desired field value 
    ' 
    For Each Lieu In Lieus
        If Lieu.LieuAdd = True Then 
          result = result + Lieu.LieuHours
        Else
          result = result - Lieu.LieuHours
        End If
     Next          
    End Sub
```

Hope this helps